# Do we need a separate Netless licenses to have whiteboard in Agora?

Tags: agora.io

We are looking to build our video streaming solution on Agora. We need the whiteboard too as shown in one of the demos. But upon trying the sdk, found that it requires netless api key. Where do we get that? Do we need a separate Netless account and pay for their product in order to have the white board?